# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'

Tags: python, python-2.6

When trying to run a python script, I get the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'`. I am using Python 2.6.

Full error:

```
File "/lib/python2.6/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 238, in get_makefile_filename
    return os.path.join(lib_dir, "config" + (sys.pydebug and "_d" or ""), "Makefile")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'
```

Comment: What is your code? What line throws the exception?

Comment: In the future you should also provide the code snippet itself. Where did you get this code from? You didn't write it yourself?

Comment: This is most likely not related to the actual script as sysconfig is imported during interpreter startup, before the user script is loaded. I get this error when running anything that embeds Python, which makes gdb on my Ubuntu 12.04 unusable. Some weird configuration problem inside the distribution packages it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think whatever you are trying to run is expecting to be used with a special debug build of python. `sys.pydebug` is not normally found on the standard release of the sys module, and I believe it would be there if you built a debug python:

http://docs.python.org/c-api/intro.html#debugging-builds

It is possible that this also might be part of a specific build that Debian/Ubuntu distros are using.

Answer (score 4):

I hit this issue when attempting to run the Ubuntu 12.04.1 system gdb on a python I built myself.  I expect Ubuntu has built some hooks into the system gdb so that it uses a debugging version of Python; but the hooks don't latch onto anything in my own python.  I got around this by building my own gdb and running that instead.

Here's the command-line and full traceback:

```
price@neverland:~/LSST/ip_diffim[master] $ gdb --args python tests/SnapPsfMatch.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 246, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 236, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 577, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 476, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 337, in _init_posix
    makefile = _get_makefile_filename()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 331, in _get_makefile_filename
    return os.path.join(get_path('platstdlib').replace("/usr/local","/usr",1), "config" + (sys.pydebug and "_d" or ""), "Makefile")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'
```

so it seems to go looking for the wrong python (in `/usr/lib`) despite my having told the system not to do so:

```
price@neverland:~/LSST/ip_diffim[master] $ which python
/home/price/eups/Linux/python/2.7.2/bin/python
price@neverland:~/LSST/ip_diffim[master] $ echo $PYTHONPATH | grep usr
price@neverland:~/LSST/ip_diffim[master] $
```

Comment: This is very likely caused by a wrong python executable lying around in your path. I used strace to find out which one it is (/usr/local/bin/python2.7 in my case), removed it and tried to reinstall python.

Comment: In my experience, omitting the non-system's Python `lib` directory from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` avoids the error (of course it doesn't allow attaching `gdb` to that Python, only running `gdb` on its own).

Answer (score 4):

I receive the error when running `gdb` on a Ubuntu system where an alternative version of Python has been installed and is being preferred by the linker. You can verify whether this is happening in your case by using `ldd` to ask which libraries `gdb` is using:

```
# ldd $(which gdb)
...
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ff75e044000)
...
```

You can see that the off-brand version of Python running in `/usr/local/lib` is supplying `libpython` to `gdb` instead of the official Ubuntu Python in `/usr/lib` which is causing the error — whatever off-brand Python this is in `/usr/local` must not have been compiled in the same way that the Ubuntu Python was compiled, and so the expectations of `gdb` are being disappointed.

The solution is to use the environment to control the linker’s behavior and make it prefer the system `libpython`. For good measure, I also reset my `PATH` back to something utterly standard. I find that this works:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib gdb ...
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubunut-12.04 pyinstaller built binaries invoke "site.py" from host python installation the call trace is trying to fetch "sys.pydebug" value.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.pydebug
False
```

The custom built python is missing this.

HACK: To make pyinstaller binaries work on Ubuntu-12.04.
Added below code change in custom built python which return zero for "sys.pydebug".

```
$ diff -Naur Python/sysmodule-org.c Python/sysmodule.c
--- Python/sysmodule-org.c      2018-03-15 09:37:26.539515000 -0700
+++ Python/sysmodule.c  2018-03-15 19:58:34.503031000 -0700
@@ -1106,6 +1106,7 @@
maxunicode -- the largest supported character\n\
builtin_module_names -- tuple of module names built into this 
interpreter\n\
version -- the version of this interpreter as a string\n\
+pydebug -- always return zero\n\
version_info -- version information as a named tuple\n\
hexversion -- version information encoded as a single integer\n\
copyright -- copyright notice pertaining to this interpreter\n\
@@ -1420,6 +1421,8 @@

     SET_SYS_FROM_STRING("version",
                      PyString_FromString(Py_GetVersion()));
+    SET_SYS_FROM_STRING("pydebug",
+                         PyInt_FromLong(0));
     SET_SYS_FROM_STRING("hexversion",
                      PyInt_FromLong(PY_VERSION_HEX));
  svnversion_init();
```