# Applications not related to python output weird error message: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, shell, syntax-error, prompt, pythonpath

Hello everybody reading this message,

Since I set PYTHONPATH on my desktop, whenever I try to use commands like gdb, or yum, which I think not related to python, I have this "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" slapping my face. I have tried several thing to debug the shell prompt, to figure out what the heck was going on, but so far I stucked with this problem.

I goes like this:

```
[charly@sn04 ~]$ gdb
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This seems to be related to PYTHONPATH. When I unset this, everything works fine.

My PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/
```

I have tried to debug the shell with -x and -v, but the debug information is not helpful:

```
[charly@sn04 ~]$ gdb
gdb
+ gdb
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried as well to set a trap:

```
trap "PARENT_COMMAND=\"$(ps -o comm= $PPID)\"" ERR
[charly@sn04 ~]$ gdb
gdb
+ gdb
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PARENT_COMMAND="xterm"
++ PARENT_COMMAND=xterm
```

, to see which process was calling this error, but so far I was unable to figure out how to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for any clue or hint.

Answer (score 3):

```
export PYTHONPATH=
```

solved my problem (Git Bash, Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of python is used by gdb (gdb uses Python for scripting)

```
$ (which gdb) | grep python
```

or

```
$ which gdb | xargs grep -a python
```

If gdb uses a different version than that in your current PYTHONPATH, then you should either change your Python path to the version supported by gdb or [re-build gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26247945/2314737)

See also:

[gdb uses wrong python](https://askubuntu.com/a/382800/619964), [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32847032/2314737), and [How to change the Python Interpreter that gdb uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26247945/2314737).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had better checked before if internaly  these commands called python or not. I couldn't think a reason why gdb would do so, but anyway it does. To complement your answer, I would re-write the command like this: which gdb | xargs grep -a python

Comment: @Dyrl I added this to my answer. But did it help to fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, but the solution is to completly remove the PYTHONPATH from my .bashrc, because it was pointing to python3.5, and gdb python2.7.I will set it inside the application I am developing, so system tools will not be affected.